# How to Include a Computed Field Decorated as `@property` in Pydantic v2 Schema for JSON Schema and Serialization?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I'm working with Pydantic v2 and trying to include a computed field in both the schema generated by `.model_json_schema()` and the serialized output from `.model_dump_json()`. I've decorated the computed field with `@property`, but it seems that Pydantic's schema generation and serialization processes do not automatically include these properties.

**Goal:**

- Ensure the computed property is included in the JSON schema generated by `.model_json_schema()`.
- Ensure the computed property is included in the serialized JSON output from `.model_dump_json()`.

**Current Approach:**
Here's a simplified version of my model where I've defined a computed property `full_name`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field

class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**Issues:**

- When calling `User.model_json_schema()`, the `full_name` field is not included in the schema.

To illustrate, here's how I'm attempting to generate the schema and serialize the model:

```py
user_instance = User(first_name="John", last_name="Doe")

# Attempt to generate JSON schema
json_schema = User.model_json_schema()
print(json_schema)  # 'full_name' is not included

# Attempt to serialize the model
serialized_output = user_instance.json()
print(serialized_output)  # 'full_name' IS included
```

**Question:**
How can I modify my Pydantic model or process to ensure that the `full_name` computed property is included both in the schema and the serialized output? I am looking for a solution that works seamlessly with Pydantic v2's features and conventions.

Comment: When you call `model_json_schema()` without parameters you have *validation* schema (that is used to create object from json data). When you generate json representation of the object, the *serialization* schema is used.

Answer (score 0):

The `mode` keyword argument to `model_json_schema()` is `'validation'` by default and doesn't include computed fields, `mode='serialization'` does.

> [JsonSchemaMode `module-attribute`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/json_schema/#pydantic.json_schema.JsonSchemaMode)
>
> ```
> JsonSchemaMode = Literal['validation', 'serialization']
> ```
>
> A type alias that represents the mode of a JSON schema; either 'validation' or 'serialization'.
>
> **For some types, the inputs to validation differ from the outputs of serialization. For example, computed fields will only be present when serializing, and should not be provided when validating.** This flag provides a way to indicate whether you want the JSON schema required for validation inputs, or that will be matched by serialization outputs.

```python
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field

class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    json_schema = User.model_json_schema()
    print(json_schema)  # 'full_name' is not included
    
    json_schema_full = User.model_json_schema(mode='serialization')
    print(json_schema_full)  # 'full_name' is included
```

Output:

```text
{'properties': {'first_name': {'title': 'First Name', 'type': 'string'}, 'last_name': {'title': 'Last Name', 'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ['first_name', 'last_name'], 'title': 'User', 'type': 'object'}
{'properties': {'first_name': {'title': 'First Name', 'type': 'string'}, 'last_name': {'title': 'Last Name', 'type': 'string'}, 'full_name': {'readOnly': True, 'title': 'Full Name', 'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ['first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name'], 'title': 'User', 'type': 'object'}
```

Related GitHub issue: [Including `computed_field` in JSON schema?](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6298)

Comment: doesnt mode `serialization` also change the schema in other surprising ways?

Comment: Possibly, depending on your model. But one of your goals is to include `computed_field` properties when calling `model_json_schema()`, which the documentation states should not be provided when validating. You could override the behavior of `model_json_schema` on the `User` class to specifically provide computed fields, but that seems counter intuitive from a validation point of view.